# Edit or Change Views/Activities Mobile Quality Assurance (MQA) IBM

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

I'm using MQA and I'm trying to edit the form fields where the fields are declared to send feedback or bug report. I understand that default activities declared:

```
<activity android:name="com.ibm.mqa.ui.ProblemActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.ibm.mqa.ui.FeedbackActivity" />
<activity android:name="com.ibm.mqa.ui.ScreenshotEditorActivity" />
```

I have been reading the documentation and I have not found a way to edit these views / layouts.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't able to edit the way the MQA form looks or functions when submitting bugs or feedback.